# Differences between jQuery's hide() and .css('display', 'none')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've changed a few pages from using generic JavaScript that sets a CSS style property

```
element.style.display = "none";
```

to jQuery's method

```
element.hide();
```

When the back button is used to return to my page, elements that were hidden using jQuery are no longer hidden. When I use raw JavaScript to set the display, the hidden elements stay hidden when I return to the page.

Is there a workaround to allow jQuery's hide() function to work the same way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery's `hide` method performs

```
        for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
            this[i].style.display = "none";
        }
```

You have some other problem.

The full method is

```
hide: function( speed, easing, callback ) {
    if ( speed || speed === 0 ) {
        return this.animate( genFx("hide", 3), speed, easing, callback);

    } else {
        for ( var i = 0, j = this.length; i < j; i++ ) {
            var display = jQuery.css( this[i], "display" );

            if ( display !== "none" ) {
                jQuery.data( this[i], "olddisplay", display );
            }
        }

        // Set the display of the elements in a second loop
        // to avoid the constant reflow
        for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
            this[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        return this;
    }
},
```

Comment: Absolutely right... there was another method nested in there that 'cached' the display property. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge difference:
When `.hide()` is called the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache, so when `.show()` is called, the initial display value is restored!

Answer (score 0):

It's the same. jQuery hide applies display: none; to the element. What is triggering your hide? Is it in the document.ready?? It seems like when you hit 'back' it does not execute the javascript.